# How do exit without quitting Terminal a command line process running when nothing else works?

Tags: docker, shell, terminal, logstash

I am working with Docker and I run a command that gets me to Docker's log - seems like. When I'm in, I cannot get back to shell prompt. I suspect it might be something with the com.docker.cli although docker-docs do not say much about an audacious exit.
I've tried everything I could find, see list. A way to reproduce the issue is:

```
docker run -e  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword mysql
```

Pressing Ctrl + opt (Alt) + T brings the process running.

Tried

- exit
- exit()
- exit N
- Ctrl + C
- Ctrl + Z
- Ctrl + X
- Ctrl + \
- Ctrl + Q
- Ctrl + S

(The above with Ctrl, also with opt and cmd without cmd+Q
which will quit Terminal)

- q
- :q
- q!
- Ctrl + D
- q()
- quit
- echo $ ?
- Esc
- !!
- Hello Kitty ^-^

All this and others and a nice combination of them.

I recommend to reproduce the issue with Docker and Terminal with the command above and get there to figure out some solutions.
The idea is to learn more about This log in Terminal and how to exit and get back to shell prompt.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a separate terminal window, run `docker ps`.  Look for a line there for a running container, with an autogenerated name, and the image `mysql`.  That's the container you manually `docker run`.

Still in that separate terminal window, run `docker stop adjective_name` with the generated container name (or, equivalently, the 12-hex-digit container ID).  This should bring back the shell prompt in the first terminal window.  You can then `docker rm adjective_name` to clean up the stopped container.

For next time:

- You can explicitly `docker run --name` to specify the name used for the container; you can then use that name with all `docker` commands.
- You can use `docker run -d` to start the container in the background, and then `docker logs container_name` to see its logs.
- You can alternately use `docker run -it` to connect the container's stdin to the console, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should work normally.

You can't really do much typing at the console of a database server, so I'd usually recommend launching it in the background.  You can use the ordinary `mysql` command-line client from your host to interact with it (make sure to add a `docker run -p` option to make its port accessible).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your collaboration. I tested the procedure and works great. The Terminal window does shows the process being finalised '[Process completed]' and leaves the window useless. The issue before running the procedure still remains and it probably does not have a possible way to get back to the prompt. As you wrote there is not much typing one can do there. I will need to get more insight on the second part of your response to get more into proper Docker use. Will see how it goes during the next few days, otherwise your submit is a good way to turn things around in this dead end.

Comment: Once again thank you for your answer. I take the tips specially running the container on the background. I'll learn more about it and also some Terminal knowledge would be handy. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[Run container in background using detached mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground).

`-d` option of `docker run` command should work.

```
docker run -d -e  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword mysql
```

This will run container in background, check if its running and capture the container id using [docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/).

Now to get into the shell of running container use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command.

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/sh
```

To check logs use `docker logs <container-id>` command, assuming you installed docker with default json-file log driver.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the explanation. I do see the precesses and ids, the above means I will need to open a new window and exit from the outside. I'm still missing a way out from where I am at, inside the ... log? it is the same log I see in the desktop app.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? In simple terms what I mean is first run container in background using `-d` option and then use `docker exec` command to get inside the shell and do whatever you want to. You can also exit out of that shell and re-exec again multiple times without crashing your msql daemon process.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand what you mean, great to know that. Although to elaborate the issue more it is about getting into a state caused by docker -e without -d and getting back to the shell prompt, to exit from where one gets to, the log fields. It might be as David Maze describes, one cannot do much typing from there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like running from within a tmux might be a good bet for you, unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean. Then you can exit and come back to what was running without stopping the process you started from the command line.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment. I prefer multiple single windows. Perhaps an option for the future. What I mean or need is the possibility to exit and getting back to the prompt, more understanding on where I'm at and how to manage inside there without quitting the terminal or killing the process.

Comment: You don't need to multiplex the window, tmux does a job of allowing you to get back to your prompt.